# Adding column based on partition by - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Table:

```
Col1       Col2         Col3
43         1234         abc
42         1234         abc
41         1234         abc
35         1234         abc
34         5678         def
```

Objective is to create a new column `Col4` as 1 or 0 based on following:

Within each partition by with `Col2 and Col3`,
either

1. if Col1-1 does not exists (or)
2. if Col1-1 (and) Col1-2 both values exists in table,
   then Col4 is 1, else 0.

Output Table:

```
 Col1            Col2         Col3        Col4
 43              1234         abc         1
 42              1234         abc         0
 41              1234         abc         1
 35              1234         abc         1
 34              5678         def         1
```

Comment: Does Col1-1 mean the first value in Col1? I'm not sure what partitioning clause you are using, or what you mean by not existing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am following the logic you describe:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lag(col1) over (partition by col2, col3 order by col1) <> col1 - 1
             then 1
             when lag(col1) over (partition by col2, col3 order by col1) is null
             then 1
             when lag(col1, 2) over (partition by col2, col3 order by col1) = col1 - 2
             then 1
             else 0
        end) as col4
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f988b92953a3077a773c04e1d6e30951) is a db<>fiddle.